# sendEmail: Linux Script and Array

Tags: linux, bash, sendmail

I have a script that send email using sendEmail (CentOS shell)
script is:

```
sendEmail -vvv -u "TestCompany, Inc.: USB Added" -f user@domain.com -t To@domain.com -s ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com -m "USB Activity" -o tls=aut
o username=user3@domain.com password=password
```

So far this works fine.

Now i create a ConfigFile as follows:

```
Company=TestCompany, Inc.
FromEmail=user@domain.com
Password=password
ToEmail=To@domain.com
Smtp=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com
```

and Now I modify my script as follow:

```
#!/bin/sh
i=1;
while IFS="=" read VAR VALUE
do
        VAR="${VAR// }"
        Values[$i]=${VALUE}
        let i++;
done <  ConfigFile

sendEmail -vvv -u "${Values[1]}: USB Added" -f ${Values[2]} -t ${Values[4]} -s ${Values[5]} -m "Test Email" -o tls=auto username=${Values[2
]} password=${Values[3]}
```

I get following error:

```
'25 failed: IO::Socket::INET: Bad hostname 'ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.comempt to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com
Apr 21 12:11:35 box2 sendEmail[26378]: HINT => Try specifying a different mail relay with the -s option.
```

Now I'm unable to understand that why I'm getting this error. even when i try to echo Values it shows me correct values. then where I'm doing wrong.? Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the singlequote that floated to the start of the line in the log message?  Your data file probably has `\r\n` for its newlines, which doesn't work very well on Unix; the carriage return is being read as part of the hostname.  Run `dos2unix` on it.